# Get div id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's some HTML:

```
<div class="results">
  <div id="1">something</div>
  <div id="2">something else</div>
  <div id="3">blah blah blah</div>
  <div id="4">etc</div>
</div>
```

Now if I can call this using jQuery:

```
var div = $(".results > div");
div.click(function()
{
  alert(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
});
```

When clicking on a div, it will call an alert box saying whats in the div (from the list above: one of 'something', 'something else', 'blah blah blah' or 'etc'). Does anyone know how I can get it to alert the id (in this example, 1, 2, 3 or 4) of the div rather than the information within the node?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the clicked `div`. You can access its [`id` property *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id):

```
alert(this.id);
```

**Note:** HTML4 does not allow `id`s to start with digits.

<del>P.S: The selector should be `$(".results > div")`.</del> *(fixed)*

Comment: Thanks! That was it! :) Yes, I know about the selector, that was a typo! Thanks though!

Comment: @ing0: Well, one never knows ;) You're welcome, happy coding!

Comment: Yea sorry, I didn't mean it like that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Alert the id property of the div:

```
alert(this.id);
```