# How to get the id of a li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of elements created dinamically. Each item has an ID.
I didn't find how to get the id of each element when it is clicked.

Nothing is working out... :(

Comment: For future references, show a code sample of what you have attempted it would go over much better then getting down-voted 3 times :(.. Welcome to SO.

Comment: and [Get div id using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7071748/218196) and many others.

Comment: Only show **relevant** code please.

Comment: No, it's not duplicate.

Comment: Only show part of the code where you are facing problem. From your question we cannot guess which part of the code posted by you needs to be edited to satisfy your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `this.id`. Inside your handler `this` will be the clicked element and you can access its `id` as a property.

Ex:

```
   $(elem).click(function(){
       var id = this.id; //Here this is the DOM element and you can access its id property
       ///Do something..
   })
```

Comment: I put my code in the question. Please, read again. Thank you

Comment: @user2963097 Try.. `$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
             var turmaEscolhida =this.id;   
             e.preventDefault();
           });`

Comment: is yourclick event getting fired at all?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I put my code in the question. Please, read again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When a click event is fired, the element that was the target of the click is stored as `this` inside of the jquery callback

```
$("li").click(function(){
 var elementClicked = this;
 var elementClickedId = this.id;
});
```

Comment: I put my code in the question. Please, read again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function getID(a)
{
    document.getElementById("showid").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
<li id="n1" onclick="getID(this);">Item1</li>
<li id="n2" onclick="getID(this);">Item2</li>
<li id="n3" onclick="getID(this);">Item3</li>

<div id="showid"></div>
```

Comment: I put my code in the question. Please, read again. Thank you